# MySql bulk load command line tool

Tags: sql, mysql, bulkinsert, load-data-infile

Does MySql have a bulk load command line tool like bcp for SQLServer and sqlldr for Oracle?  I know there's a SQL command `LOAD INFILE` or similar but I sometimes need to bulk load a file that is on a different box to the MySQL database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mysqlimport.

takes the same connection parameters as the mysql command line shell. Make sure to use the -L flag to use a file on the local file system, otherwise it will (strangely) assume the file is on the server.

There is also an analogous variant to the `load data infile` command, i.e., `load data local infile`, according to which the file will be loaded from the client rather than the server, which may accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: mysqlimport looks like what I'm after, thanks.  Only quirk I noticed is that it looks like the filename has to match the table name so maybe 'load data local infile' will be more flexible.

Comment: yeah, so you might add a symbolic link to the file before importing it.

Answer (score 6):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\path\\to\\windows\\file.CSV'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1, field2, field3, fieldx);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm think mysqlimport may help?

Loads tables from text files in various formats.  The base name of the
text file must be the name of the table that should be used.
If one uses sockets to connect to the MySQL server, the server will open and
read the text file directly. In other cases the client will open the text
file. The SQL command 'LOAD DATA INFILE' is used to import the rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -u root -p
use database;
source /path/yourfile.sql
```

Might be what you are looking for, you can use rsync via ssh to transfert the 'bulk file' from a machine to another.