# How can I force Entity Framework Code First to accept "out of phase" foreign key types, db table vs .NET entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an inherited Code First Entity Framework project where the entities in C# have fallen out of phase with the database. When I attempt to create a parent-to-child 1-to-1 relationship with an existing table, EF is unable to create valid SQL for establishing the foreign key (FK) relationship.

In this case, the parent entity is called `ApplicantRegistration`. I need to relate this, one-to-one, with the `User` entity to represent a `CaseManager` that belongs to each applicant. (The `User` entity is used as a child relation in many more parent entities.)

Simple enough on its face. I added the following to the `ApplicantRegistration`...

```
public User CaseManager { get; set; }
```

But the `User` has an id that says this...

```
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    // ...
```

... and, in MySQL, the `Users` *table* related to that entity has this...

```
  `UserId` bigint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

**>>>** Since `bigint` and `int` don't jibe, I get an error when EF tries to create a Foreign Key. **<<<**

The int column (EF names it `CaseManager_UserId`) gets added to the `ApplicantRegistrations` table fine, but the FK creation borks.

Here's the autogenerated EF SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE ApplicantRegistrations
ADD COLUMN CaseManager_UserId int NULL
CREATE INDEX IX_ApplicantRegistrations_CaseManager_UserId ON ApplicantRegistrations (CaseManager_UserId)
ALTER TABLE ApplicantRegistrations
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ApplicantRegistrations_Users_CaseManager_UserId FOREIGN KEY (CaseManager_UserId) REFERENCES Users (UserId)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

`ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ApplicantRegistrations_Users_CaseManager_UserId FOREIGN KEY (CaseManager_UserId)` isn't going to work, because `int` and `bigint` don't match.

---

### Options Considered

#### 1. Swap `int` to `long` in `User` in the C#

I originally started swapping from `int` for `UserId` on the `User` entity over to `long` (this is in C#) to see if that'd match up with `bigint` in EF's generated code, but that quickly became a mess, practically speaking. After I swapped `public int UserId { get; set; }` over to `public long UserId { get; set; }` *and* fixed the fallout from changing type on related entities & code, I received a number of errors like the following when trying to `Add-Migration`:

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> ProgramWorksite_WorksiteAdministratorUser_Target_ProgramWorksite_WorksiteAdministratorUser_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'WorksiteAdministratorUserId' on entity 'ProgramWorksite' does not match the type of property 'UserId' on entity 'User' in the referential constraint 'ProgramWorksite_WorksiteAdministratorUser'.

That makes sense, of course -- now I've got to change all the other places `User` is used as a child relation. (There are 33 of them, and it occurs to me there should be an easier way, so I shelved `int` to `long` in `User` for now in the hopes of finding something better, but I'll probably come back to this after posting.)

#### 2. Swap `bigint` for `int` in `Users` in MySQL

I also tried to swap from `bigint` to `int` in MySQL, but that would require dropping & replacing tons of FK relationships with `UserId` in the database, which is a possible solution, but not much fun. I think fixing it in the C# would be easier -- **assuming `long` will map to `bigint`**, which I don't know for sure. (**UPDATE:** `long` does map to `bigint(15)`, at least in this system.)

#### 3. Try annotating the column in `ApplicantRegistration`

I thought I might be able to use a `Column` override for EF's purposes only like this inside of `Applicant`...

```
Column("CaseManagerId", TypeName = "bigint(15)")]
public User CaseManager { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately, that gave the same error as before -- and it didn't use the `CaseManagerId` name I'd used, instead defaulting back to `CaseManager_UserId`. So, at best, I've done the annotation wrong.

The annotation route really is my favorite, if there's a way to make it work -- if it could make EF ignore what's in the `User` entity's `UserId` definition long enough to create the FK relationship and complete the migration, I'm golden.

---

What's the most efficient way to insert this new relationship if I don't want to drop EF Code First?

Comment: I would just change MySQL back to int.  Unless you are planning to have more values than that number, which I wouldn't expect for a list of users.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 But unfortunately, as I noted in 2., that would involve dropping and recreating every FK relationship involving the `Users` table that's in the existing database. That's exceptionally non-trivial, afaict. But perhaps I'm missing something? I don't think there's an easy way to change `UserId` in the database to an `int` without dropping & recreating those relationships. (This is a system that's been in production for years, if that helps with context. I can't simply create a new migration and greenfield it. That said, I completely agree that `bigint` is overkill here.)

Comment: i would think it would support going to a smaller column size assuming the values in there all support it...you would drop the FKs...alter the columns on tables involved...recreate FKs...it would have to be done during a period of system maintainable id assume

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Yep, that's why I'd like to find a more expedient solution. Is there a way to tell Entity Framework, "_Hey, I know it says `int` in C#, but when you're writing SQL, pretend it's a `bigint(15)`, ok?_" Because if there is, I've got the new migration in and at least the database's isn't worse than it was before.

Comment: Okay, this was ugly. For now, I'm changing the migration code's `Up` method (by hand, after it's auto-generated by `Add-Migration`) from `AddColumn("dbo.ApplicantRegistrations", "CaseManager_UserId", c => c.Int());` to `AddColumn("dbo.ApplicantRegistrations", "CaseManager_UserId", c => c.Long());` -- which is to say, I'm swapping `c => c.Int()` for `c => c.Long()`. I don't feel good about that, but it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm hoping someone will come back and tell me there's a better way and I can move the check, but for now, here's what I'm doing...

---

Since all `Add-Migration` is really doing is auto-generating some C#, you can take that autogenerated code and hack it to match your use case -- in this case, ignoring that the entity is using `int` and the database is using `bigint`/`long`.

Hacking the migration code before running `Update-Database` breaks nothing. That is, there's nothing checking to make sure your migrations for your datastore match your entity definitions (in code) before the migration C# is run.

In my case, that means I needed to change this `Up` method from what the autogenerated code was...

```
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.ApplicantRegistrations", 
                "CaseManager_UserId", c => c.Int());

            CreateIndex("dbo.ApplicantRegistrations", "CaseManager_UserId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.ApplicantRegistrations", "CaseManager_UserId", "dbo.Users", "UserId");
        }
```

... to this...

```
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.ApplicantRegistrations",
                "CaseManager_UserId", c => c.Long()); // <<< This from Int to Long

            CreateIndex("dbo.ApplicantRegistrations", "CaseManager_UserId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.ApplicantRegistrations", "CaseManager_UserId", "dbo.Users", "UserId");
        }
```

This is [smelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

As [@Ctznkane525 remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60010539/how-can-i-force-entity-framework-code-first-to-accept-out-of-phase-foreign-key#comment106131548_60010539), since we're unlikely to get past 2147483647 users in this application, `bigint` is overkill, and the maintainers of this system (possibly including me) should eventually take option #2 from the OP, and fix the danged schema at some point.

> So the quick fix (and the answer to this specific question) is to make EF ignore the out of phase entity and schema by hacking the migration file/C# code.

The Long Term Right Thing To Do, however, is to make the database schema and entity code match. Maybe you [bcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626059/mysql-bulk-load-command-line-tool) the data out, massage the db with `int` from `bigint`, and recreate the schema if production can stand some downtime, or maybe you bite the bullet and stick with insanely big `bigint`s in your schema and finish doing #1 from the question to make the EF code match and rerun your initial migration. But for now, a hack it is.

Comment: You could also fiddle with the current `DatabaseModelSnapshot` so it matches the types in the database. Then generate a migration...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman DatabaseModelSnapshot is regenerated on each new migration to my knowledge, I don't think that would work. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Creating a migration compares the `dbContext.Model` with the previous snapshot, then serialises the model to overwrite the snapshot. If you fiddle with the snapshot directly, so it mirrors your actual schema (maybe by scaffolding a new context in a new project?) then creating a migration should bring your schema in line with your model...